# How to post a choice of options to Microsoft Teams asynchronously?

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I have a website developed using ASP.NET Core 5.0. I would like to implement Approve / Reject approval workflow from the website at a point in the application. So created an Azure Logic App as shown in the below screenshot which can be invoked from the website. The three steps in logic app are:

1. HTTP Request - when a HTTP request is received
2. post a choice of options as the flow bot to a user (one of the actions in Microsoft Teams)
3. HTTP Response - To send user's selection / response back

[image]

[image]

The logic app sends a message to the user in Microsoft Teams and captures the user's response, either Approve or Reject successfully. But this is all synchronous i.e. the logic app is waiting until the user is responded.

If the user takes two days to respond to the message in Teams to Approve or Reject, my code calling the logic app has to wait for two days too which is not desirable.

Is there any way to implement this functionality asynchronously?

1. Send a message from the application / website to Microsoft Teams and do not wait synchronously
2. Capture the user's response (Approve / Reject) from Teams and record it in application / website

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first requirement(`Send a message from the application / website to Microsoft Teams and do not wait synchronously`), you can set the "**Response**" action as `Asynchronous`. Click "**Settings**" of the "**Response**" action and enable `Asynchronous Response`.

[image]

[image]

After this configuration, when you request the url, it will response `202` status and response body directly(without waiting user's respond) like below screenshot.
[image]

For your second requirement(`Capture the user's response (Approve / Reject) from Teams and record it in application / website`), you can add a "**HTTP**" action after the "**Post a choice of options as the Flow bot to a user**" action to record user's response. You need to develop a api and set the api in the "**HTTP**" action `URI` input box to record user's response.
[image]

The whole logic app show like:
[image]